# Azure front door custom domain resolves to app service default domain

Tags: azure, .net-6.0, azure-appservice, azure-authentication, azure-front-door

I have an api application in .net 6 deployed in an app service (apiappservice: apiappservice.azurewebsites.net) which has a azure front door(classic) in front of it with a custom domain.

Part of Startup of api application

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>
        {
            option.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MY API", Version = "v1" });
            option.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "Enter valid token",
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                BearerFormat = "JWT",
                Scheme = "Bearer"
            });
            option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id="Bearer"
                        }
                    },
                    Array.Empty<string>()
                }
            });
        });

        services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(opts => opts.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)
            .AddOData(options => options.Filter());

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options),
                                                options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddMyApiPolicies();
            options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
        });

        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

When I browse my custom domain, abc.com/swagger I get the swagger index html but the address resolves to appservice default domain apiappservice.azurewebsites.net

What do I do to fix this?